# Escaping colons in Docker Compose value

Tags: docker-compose

I'm trying to pass some parameters to my healthcheck test :

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
    mongodb:
        image: mongo
        container_name: mongodb
        environment:
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${MONGODB_USER}
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MONGODB_PASS}
        volumes:
            - ./db:/data/db
        networks:
            - proxy
        restart: unless-stopped
        healthcheck:
            test: test $$(echo "rs.initiate({_id: 'rs0', members: [{_id: 1, 'host': 'mongodb:27017'}]}).ok || rs.status().ok" | mongosh -u $${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME} -p $${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD} --quiet) -eq 1
            interval: 10s
            start_period: 30s
```

I'm getting this error :

```bash
yaml: mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

If I remove the colons (:) it works. How can I escape these colons in my test value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution. Colons need to be escaped with quotes, and I used double quotes elsewhere for clarity :

```
test: test $$(echo 'rs.initiate({_id':' "rs0", members':' [{_id':' 1, "host"':' "mongodb':'27017"}]}) || rs.status().ok' | mongosh -u $${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME} -p $${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD} --quiet) -eq 1
```